# In Azure Pipeline how to use the Docker container name in a variable to use in a replace tokens task?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I have created an Azure DevOps pipeline and I can not figure out how to get and use the docker container name that is created in the docker task to use later in the pipeline when I run a shell script task to deploy the container.

1 - I build a Docker image. I see that is has the image name "containerapp$(Build.BuildId)" populated:
[image]

2 - I have a "Push image to Amazon ECR" task which also has the "containerapp$(Build.BuildId)" populated:
[image]

3 - I try populating a variable in the variable group I am using to use the "containerapp$(Build.Build.id)" but that does not work later on when I try and use the variable:
[image]

I have my Kubernetes yaml file populated with the IMAGE_ID variable which is utilized in a replace tokens task -

```
containers:
        - image:  #{IMAGE_ID}#
         name: app 
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-files mountPath: /var/www/html
```

I know that the replace tokens works because if I change the IMAGE_ID variable to be a valid container image location my deploy will work.

How do I populate the variable to use whatever is autogenerated to be the container name that is created by Azure DevOps?

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Test to use the `Replace Token` task to replace the value in K8s yaml file, the variable `containerapp$(Build.BuildId)` could work as expected.

Here is Replace Token Task Settings:

[image]

Variable Group:

[image]

Result：

[image]

Based on my test, docker task can't directly output image name variable, so we could create a variable to save the name. Just like you did.

To manage variables more convenient, you can improve your method.

You could direclty set the $(IMAGE_ID) variable as the Image name in Docker task and Push task.

[image]

In this case, you only need to change the variables in the variable group once, and you can change the variables in the image name and yaml files at the same time.